# Counting number of levels within another variable level in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, levels

I have a data frame with two character variables, state and birds. I'm trying to see how many bird types are within each state. I have tried:

```
data.frame %>%
   group_by(state) %>%
   n_distinct(data.frame$bird)

data.frame %>%
   group_by(state) %>%
   n_distinct(unique(data.frame$bird))
```

However, I am very stuck. Thank you in advance for your help; let me know if I need to add more clarification.

Comment: Try `data.frame %>% group_by(state, bird) %>% tally()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
data.frame %>%
   group_by(state) %>%
   summarize(distinct_birds = n_distinct(data.frame$bird))
```

Comment: This ended up working except I had to use the summarize function instead of mutate. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will be very simple using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt=data.table(data.frame)

dt[,counts:=.N, by=.(state,birds)]
```

- `.N` is the data.table function to get counts
- `by` include grouping variables.

Answer (score -1):

Also using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame %>% count(state)
```